# How to handle the exception thrown by the async method with observable?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have an observable and I would like to subscribe this observable with an async method, however each time the exception thrown by the async method, the subscription disposed immediately even if I put the catch code in the observable definition. The pseudo code as follow to demonstrate this situation:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test()
{
    var observable = Observable.Create<int>(observer =>
    {
        try
        {
            Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                observer.OnNext(x);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // get called after the exception is thrown 
            _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"The exception is catch:{ex.ToString()}"); 
        }
        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
           // also get called after exception is thrown
            _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Observable Dispose"); 
        });
    });

    Func<int, Task> handler = async (i) =>
     {
         // simulate the handler logic
         await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
         // throw the exception to test 
         throw new Exception($"{i}");
     };

    observable.Subscribe(x=>handler(x).Wait());

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}
```

From above code, I don`t understand why the dispose delegate get called even the exception is catch (For some reason, I have to deal with the exception inside the observable definition), Is there any way to prevent the subscription being disposed when the exception thrown from async method?

Comment: What do you mean by "dispose delegate"? Do you mean the call to Disposable.Create?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes！the action delegate of Disposable.Create is get called

Comment: It is called because you swallow the exception rather than rethrowing it. For the purpose of all code that follows, there might as well never have been an exception thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening in your code is a direct consequence of you using `Observable.Create` and filling the observable with this code:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    observer.OnNext(x);
});
```

`Observable.Create` uses the current thread to create the observable, so the `Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList().ForEach` executes immediately on the current thread and the call to `OnNext` executes the `handler(x).Wait()` immediately.

You'll note, though, that the exception occurs in the delegate passed to the `Subscribe`. Internally there is code like this:

```
catch (Exception exception)
{
    if (!autoDetachObserver.Fail(exception))
    {
        throw;
    }
    return autoDetachObserver;
}
```

That catches the exception in the subscribe, cancels the subscription - hence the `"Observable Dispose"` message - and then rethrows the exception and that's where your code catches it.

Now, if you wanted to do this properly in Rx, you'd avoid `Observable.Create`. It's a tempting way to create observables, but it leads to trouble.

Instead do this:

```
public async Task Test()
{
    Func<int, Task> handler = async (i) =>
     {
         // simulate the handler logic
         await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
         // throw the exception to test 
         throw new Exception($"{i}");
     };
 
    await
        Observable
            .Range(1, 10)
            .SelectMany(i => Observable.FromAsync(() => handler(i)))
            .LastOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

But, of course, we want to handle the exception. The simple way is like this:

```
public async Task Test()
{
    Func<int, Task> handler = async (i) =>
     {
         // simulate the handler logic
         await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
         // throw the exception to test 
         throw new Exception($"{i}");
     };
 
    await
        Observable
            .Range(1, 10)
            .SelectMany(i =>
                Observable
                    .FromAsync(() => handler(i))
                    .Catch<Unit, Exception>(ex =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"The exception is catch:{ex.ToString()}");
                        return Observable.Empty<Unit>();
                    }))
            .LastOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

That now outputs the 10 exception errors and completes normally.

Comment: Instead of `.SelectMany(/*...*/)` I would prefer `.Select(/*...*/).Merge(1)`, to prevent concurrent invocations of the asynchronous `handler`. The handler might not be designed with concurrency in mind, as it's normally the case with synchronous handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing exactly what you told it to.

The purpose of catching an exception is so that your program can continue without abruptly stopping. That's exactly what your code is doing: the exception is caught, then execution continues after the `catch` block.

If you want it to do something else, you have two options.

1. Rethrow the exception after logging it:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // get called after the exception is thrown 
    _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"The exception is catch:{ex.ToString()}");
    throw;
}
```

Then, whatever code called `Test()` will have the responsibility of catching that exception (or not).

2. Move the return inside the `try` block and return something else when the exception is caught:

```
try
{
    Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        observer.OnNext(x);
    });
    return Disposable.Create(() =>
    {
       // also get called after exception is thrown
        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Observable Dispose"); 
    });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // get called after the exception is thrown 
    _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"The exception is catch:{ex.ToString()}");
    
    return //something else
}
```

You may benefit from reading Microsoft's documentation on [Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/exception-handling).

Comment: This answer really doesn't give any discussion regarding the question actually asked - "Is there any way to prevent the subscription being disposed when the exception thrown from async method?"

Comment: It also doesn't discuss the intricacies around how exceptions are handled when using Rx.