# Rx .Net doesn't continue sequence after an error is caught

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I'm sowewhat new to rx and currently I am using it to schedule a cron job which is continuously polling a server via grpc (found that solution a time ago here on Stackoverflow).

The polling function with rx:

```
Observable.Interval(Timespan)
    .Select(l => Observable.FromAsync(() => Job(m_CTS.Token)))
    .Concat()
    .Catch((Exception ex) => OnErrorFunc(ex))
    .Subscribe(m_CTS.Token);`
```

The error function which handles the occurring error:

```
private IObservable<System.Reactive.Unit> OnError(Exception aException)
{
    LOG.Error("CronJob failed " + Job.Method+ " " + aException.Message );
    return Observable.Empty<System.Reactive.Unit>();
}
```

When the task fails e.g. the server is not available, an exception is thrown. Rx catches the error with the error function, but doesn't continue to schedule/fire the task.

Apparently the empty observable is not sufficient for the sequence to continue.

I already tried to return an

```
Observable.FromAsync(() => Job(m_CTS.Token))
```

but this doesn't work either.

What is the correct return type to get the sequence going? Or maybe my approach is wrong? Is `.Retry` the better option?

To elimnate confusion here the whole class:

```
public class CronJob : ICronJob
{

    private CancellationTokenSource m_CTS;
    private static readonly ILog LOG = LogManager.GetLogger( System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType );
    public Func<CancellationToken,Task> Job{ get; private set; }
    public Func<Exception,IObservable< System.Reactive.Unit>> OnErrorFunc { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Timespan;
    public bool Running { get; private set; } = false;
    
    public CronJob(Func<CancellationToken,Task> aJob, TimeSpan aTimeSpan, Func<Exception,IObservable<System.Reactive.Unit>> aOnErrorFunc = null)
    {
        Job= aJob;
        Timespan = aTimeSpan;
        OnErrorFunc = aOnErrorFunc ?? OnError;
        m_CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
    
    public void StartInstantly()
    {
        StartTask();
        Observable.Interval(Timespan)
            .StartWith(-1L)
            .Select(l => Observable.FromAsync(() => Job(m_CTS.Token)))
            .Concat()
            .Catch((Exception ex) => OnErrorFunc(ex))
            .Subscribe(m_CTS.Token);
    }

    private void StartTask()
    {
        if (Running)
            throw new Exception("Task allready started");

        m_CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Running = true;
    }

    public void StartAfterTimeSpan()
    {
        StartTask();
        
        Observable.Interval(Timespan)
            .Select(l => Observable.FromAsync(() => Job(m_CTS.Token)))
            .Concat()
            .Catch((Exception ex) => OnErrorFunc(ex))
            .Subscribe(m_CTS.Token);
            
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        m_CTS.Cancel();
        Running = false;
    }

    public void SetTask(Func<CancellationToken,Task> aJob)
    {
        if(Running)
            Stop();
        Job= aJob;
    }

    private IObservable<System.Reactive.Unit> OnError(Exception aException)
    {
        LOG.Error("CronJob failed " + Job.Method+ " " + aException.Message );
      // return Observable.Empty<System.Reactive.Unit>();
      return Observable.Empty<System.Reactive.Unit>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the `OnErrorFunc` and the `OnError` the same misspelled method?

Comment: Yep it is.. OnErrorFunc is a Function of Type <Exception, System.Reactive.Unit> which you can specify in the constructor of the class. The OnError function is the standard function if you dont provide one. Sry for not mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

`Retry` combined with `Catch` is closer to what you're looking for.

Normally, an exception terminates the observable pipeline, by sending an Error notification to the subscription. `Catch` catches the Error notification, and replaces it with the new observable in `Catch` parameter. In your case, that's an `Empty`: So the observable pipeline would terminate normally (with a Completed notification), but it would still terminate.

`Retry` suppresses the Error notification and tries to resubscribe the whole pipeline. Something like this is probably what you're after:

```
    var retryLimit = 3;
    Observable.Interval(Timespan)
        .StartWith(-1L)
        .Select(l => Observable.FromAsync(() => Task(m_CTS.Token)))
        .Concat()
        .Catch((Exception ex) => OnErrorFunc(ex))
        .Retry(retryLimit) // will permanently die after 3 errors
        .Subscribe(m_CTS.Token);
```

For further reading, I recommend this documentation: http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html#Catch

Answer (score 0):

If found what I was missing in an older question here on SO in an answer from @Enigmativity https://stackoverflow.com/a/70695753/11957956

First note I renamed my  `public Func<CancellationToken,Task> Task` to  `public Func<CancellationToken,Task> Job` to impede confusion. (I also edited my original question)

To get it running I wrapped my Job into a Func:

```
Func<long, Task> handler = async (i) =>
            {
                await Job(m_CTS.Token);
            };
```

and pass it like that:

```
Observable
 .Interval(Timespan)
 .Select(i => Observable.FromAsync(() => handler(i))
 .Catch<System.Reactive.Unit, Exception>(ex => OnErrorFunc(ex)))
 .Concat()
 .LastOrDefaultAsync()
 .Subscribe(m_CTS.Token);
```

@Shlomo Answer will also work. Which is the better soulition,IDK maybe someone with more experience can chime in and I will mark the best answer.